# Django Admin Inline and Schema Design

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My desire is to have a common location model, and then have the various higher level models who need a location refer to it.

I want to present my user in admin with a multiple part form (an inline) that allows them to enter the higher level info for the Publisher and Building, as well as the location information for each.   The inline system doesn't seem to want to work this way.

Clearly, I am doing something very wrong, because this seems like a very standard sort of problem to me.  Is my schema design borked ?

Am I stupidly using the inline system ?  I don't want to do subclasses of Location for each upper level object, because I want to manipulate locations in different ways independent of whatever high-level objects own them (a mailing list, or geographic look up perhaps)

```
models.py:
...
class Location(models.Model):
    """
    A geographical address
    """
# Standard Location stuff   
    address_line1 = models.CharField("Address line 1", max_length = 45, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Publisher(models.Model):
    """
    Contains Publisher information for publishers of yearbooks.  Replaces Institution from 1.x
    """
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, help_text="Name of publisher, e.g. University of Kansas")
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, help_text="Select groups that this publisher owns.  Usually just one, but multiple groups are possible.")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(help_text="Check this box to enable this publisher.")
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location)
    ...

class Building(models.Model):
    """
    Contains Building Information
    """
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, help_text="Name of building, e.g. Physical Sciences")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(help_text="Check this box to enable this building.")
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location)
    ...

admin.py:
...
class LocationInline(generic.GenericStackedInline):
    model = Location
    max_num = 1
    extra = 1

class PublisherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Publisher
    inlines = [ LocationInline,
    ]

class BuildingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Building
    inlines = [ LocationInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Publisher, PublisherAdmin)
admin.site.register(Building, BuildingAdmin)
```

I can force the inline to load and present by adding this to the Location model:

```
# Support reverse lookup for admin  
    object_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    of           = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id' )
```

But when I do this, even though I do get an inline object, and can edit it, the relationship seems backwards to me, with Location storing an id to the object that created it.

Any help is welcome, either a recommended schema change to make everything work wonderfully (as Django is so good at) or a trick to make the backwards-seeming stuff make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you want ForeignKey, not OneToOneField. Otherwise, you might as well just add your location fields to the Publisher and Building models. Then you'll simply get a dropdown to choose the location and a link to add a new one if needed in the building and publisher admin.

If you really want to have one location instance per building/publisher, you won't be able to edit it as an inline because an inline model needs to have a ForeignKey pointing to the parent model, unless you add the generic foreign key. This isnt 'backwards' - it's a valid option when you want an object to be able to attach itself to any other, regardless of type.

Comment: That's what I was missing Greg.  The notion of attaching _itself_ to another object, without the 'parent' object having any awareness.  My OneToOne field is superfluous in that situation.  Got it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to domain model, there's no such thing as a "One Right Way" to do it, it depends on your specific application's requirements.

wrt/ your problem:

The OneToOne field limits your models to one Location per model instance, which (as Greg mentionned) is not *conceptually* very different from just sticking the Location's fields directly in the model. wrt/ DRY/factorisation/reuse etc, you can get this done using model inheritence too, having an abstract (or eventually concrete if it makes sense for your app) Location model.

The ForeignKey solution still restricts your Publisher and Building models to a single Location (which might - or not - be what you want), but a given location might be shared between different Publisher and / or Building instances. This means that editing one given location will reflect on all the related instances (beware of unwanted side effects here).

Using a GenericForeignKey in the Location model means that a given location instance belongs to one *and only one* related object. No surprinsing side-effect as with the above solution but you may have duplicate locations (ie one for the building, one for the publisher) with same values, and you won't be able to lookup all related objects for a specific location (or not that easily at least). Also, this won't prevent a Publisher or Building instance to have more than one location, which once again might be fine or not. wrt/ Location instance "storing the id" of the object they belong to, well, that's really what this design choice means : a Location "belongs to" some other object, period.

In any case, designing around the default behaviour of Django's admin app is probably not the wisest thing to do. You have to first decide what makes sense for **this** application (and you may have different needs for Publishers and Buildings), then possibly extend the admin to match your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm aware of the general limitations of FK's and OneToOne.  Greg in the answer below sorted me out.  It was a conceptual hangup on my part, thinking I had to have a forward reference FROM my parent TO the child, when in fact, what I really want is a child that can attach _itself_ to an arbitrary parent.